# Best fuel for supercar engines

Tags: energy-efficiency, fuel-economy

To experienced supercar owners/engineers:

What is the best fuel for a turbocharged 6 liter V8, 7.6 liter V10, or 9.2 liter V12 (Audi R8 or Lamborghini Aventador type cars) in terms of speed/horsepower efficiency and minimization of wear on the engine? Mileage efficiency can be discarded (it can do 4 gallons per mile... not a problem :) ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fuel specified by the manufacturer in the car's manual and/or near the gas cap. Likely a High Octane Fuel based on your question.

If you're referring to Octane levels... The higher the Octane, the harder it is to ignite the fuel. In the case of High Compression Engines(typically in sports cars like you mention in your question) lower octane fuel can detonate on the compression stroke before the piston actually reaches the point where the spark plug fires. This is not good. Higher octane fuels will not pre-detonate under higher compression.

*Newer* engines can handle lower octane, but performance will suffer.

You can read more here: [A bit about early detonation](http://www.contactmagazine.com/Issue54/EngineBasics.html)